# Preselecting options in cascading <select> menus created via XMLHTTP

Tags: ajax, xmlhttprequest, selected, cascadingdropdown

I've set up a series of 3 cascading select menus with options taken from a MySQL database.  I'm using the onchange event to trigger javascript that uses XmlHttpRequest to replace the options of the 2nd menu based on the selection made in the first, and then to replace options of the 3rd menu based on the selection made in the second.  Everything works great there.

But then I want to pre-fill the form with data.  This is for a timecard, so each row consists of menus to choose the project type, project number, and task number, and then the hours for each day, so I have to pre-fill the selected options and numbers for time already filled in.  As I read in data, I call a function with the select menu's ID, the value of the item that I want selected, and whether or not this item should be set readonly.

```
function preselectMyItem(menuId, itemToSelect, locked) {
   // Get a reference to the drop-down\n";
   var myDropdownList = document.getElementById(menuId);
//   alert(menuId + ', ' + itemToSelect + ', ' + locked);
   // Loop through all the items
   for (iLoop = 0; iLoop< myDropdownList.options.length; iLoop++) {
      if (myDropdownList.options[iLoop].value == itemToSelect) {
         // Item is found. Set its selected property, and exit the loop
         myDropdownList.options[iLoop].selected = true;
         myDropdownList.options[iLoop].readonly = locked;
         myDropdownList.onchange();
         break;
      }
   }
}
```

This function works great for the first menu when I call like this (in PHP) while looping through the rows:

```
   if($myCurrentProjectType[$row]) {
     echo "<script>preselectMyItem('program_type_$row', '$myCurrentProjectType[\
$row]', 1)</script>";
   }
```

But the calls for the 2nd and 3rd menus don't work

```
   if($myCurrentProjectNum[$row]) {
     echo "<script>preselectMyItem('program_id_$row', '$myCurrentProjectNum[$ro\
w]', 1)</script>";
   }
   if($myCurrentTaskNum[$row]) {
     echo "<script>preselectMyItem('task_id_$row', '$myCurrentTaskNum[$row]', 1\
)</script>";
```

If I uncomment the alert() in the preselectMyItem() function, I can see that the function is being called with the correct arguments.  However, the onchange triggered by the first menu happens too late, and the 2nd and 3rd menus aren't populated by the time I try to preselect in them.  I pulled the above two calls out into their own for() loops through the rows, but it's still too early.

The asynchronous nature of XmlHttpRequest is nice, but it's giving me fits here.  Is there a way for me to know when the onchange function has completed for the first menu (which, presumably, I can reuse for the second menu when I get there)?  Or perhaps a better way of doing this whole thing?

Thanks!

EDIT: fixed the code formatting, and for the sake of not plagiarizing, preselectMyItem() is based on code I found here:  http://imar.spaanjaars.com/292/how-do-i-preselect-an-item-in-a-drop-down-list

Comment: I tried to do the selection a different way, by having the onchange of the first menu feed the desired element into the called php file, so that the option is selected when XmlHttpRequest sends its response.  This worked to set the 2nd selection menu, but it didn't trigger its onchange to set the 3rd.  So then I added a call to onchange just after the innerHtml is set, but all that did was populate the third selection menu (without actually tagging an element as selected).  Back to the drawing board...

Comment: Ok, I think I've solved (or at least hacked) the problem.  I kept everything above the same, but then added an onchange function to the 3rd select menu.  It calls a modified version of preselectMyItem() that takes a fourth element.  The fourth element is the value of the 3rd select menu.  If it's set, then the function exits. If it's not set, then it behaves as normal, setting the "selected" flag of the desired item.  This way, if I'm preloading values, they'll get selected.  But if the user wants to change an item, it won't get overridden by the preloaded value.